# Can I enable replies to older posts in Google Groups?

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups

From Google Groups Help:

> You can reply to any message in Google Groups that was posted in the last 60 days. After 60 days, the option to post a reply to the message is removed. In Usenet proper, inactive articles are usually retired (removed completely). Removing the option to post a reply to a message more than 60 days old simulates this feature in Google Groups.

What I want to know is whether it is possible to override this default behaviour for your own Group and allow replies to be posted to older posts  - specifically using Google Apps Premier for our own domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post a message to a closed thread thus:

1. log in with a subscribed account
2. click the 'forward' button on the post in the conversation that you want to reply to
3. put the group email address as the recipient
4. change 'FW: ' to 'RE: ' at the start of the subject line
5. write your reply and send

*Source: http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/c3e3e6f250f4dcd6*

Comment: turns out you _have_ to follow that method; I think this is to retain some header ID / meta data information from the original message, without which it creates a new thread even if you change the subject. If you clarify that in your answer I'll accept as correct.

Comment: @Foley. Very strange! I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 2):

While probably you won't be able to do it directly from the Google Group site, I think it should be possible to simply reply to that thread from your GMail, if you have mail notifications enabled. So if at least one of you will do that, then everybody should be able to post again for the next 60 days. Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: I wasn't set up to receive emails, so I didn't have a message to reply to. So, I tried emailing the group with the same subject but it simply posted my email as a new thread :(

Comment: @Foley, it may be necessary to prefix the subject with 'Re: '. I cannot confirm that this works, but [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/c3e3e6f250f4dcd6) claims that it does.

Comment: @Ian thanks, got it working following that post! You click forward, address the forwarded message to the group email address, edit the "FW:..." to "RE:..." and send :)

Comment: @Ian do you want to post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @FoleyIsGood I'm marking this answer as a community wiki so you can also edit it and change the answer to reflect the actual solution