# How to register for email replies to existing Google Groups posts

Tags: google-groups

I've posted a topic to a Google Group. I forgot to select the **Email updates to me** checkbox:

[image]

I have several such existing posts, and now would like to enable replies to be sent to me by email. Is there a way to retroactively "check" that box on existing posts?

This is not the same thing as [Can I enable replies to older posts in Google Groups?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11168/can-i-enable-replies-to-older-posts-in-google-groups)

Answer (score 2):

Under the title, beside the number of posts is a drop-down button (circle with down arrow). One of the options here is 'Email updates to me'. Is that what you're looking for?